# Register abstract class with autofac

Tags: autofac, dbconnection, idbconnection

I just run this code in a quickly made console app with autofac assembly added:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbConnection>().As<IDbConnection>().WithParameter("connectionString", connectionString);
```

There was no exception although DbConnection is of abstract type.

Does autofac really create a concrete instance of DbConnection although its abstract?

How is that possible not to use:

builder.RegisterType().As().WithParameter("connectionString", connectionString);

Do I have to inherit from DbConnection and inject then MySqlConnection inherited from DbConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only get the exception on resolution. You do need to register concrete types since you can't instantiate abstract types. So, as you said, you'd need a non-abstract type with a public constructor derived from DbConnection and register that as IDbConnection.